# Count XML Nodes PHP

Tags: php, xml, count

I'm faily new XML within PHP, and was hoping you clever people out there would be able to help me. Let's say I have an xml document which is full of users. Let me give you an example one of the users:

```
<user name="Cajs">
    <email>mail@cajs.co.uk</email>
    <server>Alpha</server>
    <referral>VQxwf3Wq4PS5WOqhljTDPUbA</referral>
    <limit>10</limit>
    <ips />
    <network id="EsperNet" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="DALnet" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="Freenode" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="OnlineGamesNet" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="PonyChat" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="QuakeNet" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="Rizon" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="YourBNC" created="1388534400"/>
    <network id="AthemeNet" created="1406458342"/>
</user>
```

How would I count the total amount of networks of "ALL" users who have the server Alpha.

Thanks for all help!

*** UPDATE ***
Please is it possible for when the removed= part is added to the  tag it's ignored, example below:

Comment: What XML api are you planning to use in your PHP code? SimpleXML? DOMDocument?  This pretty easy with either, using an XPath query. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: printf($xml['network'], $xml->count());

Comment: I don't mind whichever API method. As long as it works, I'm happy. Thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski would you be able to present me a coded example? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with help of XPath:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$results = array();

foreach($xml->xpath('//user[server[.="Alpha"]]') as $user) {
    $results[] = array(
                       'name'          => (string)$user->attributes()->name,
                       'network_count' => $user->network->count()
                      );
}

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: As an Update: I used this:
`foreach ($servers as $server) {
$user[$server] = $xml->query("/users/user[server='".$server."' and not(@removed)]/network");
$total += $user[$server]->length;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$countUsers = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < $xml->count(); $i++ ) {
    if( $xml->user[$i]->server == 'Alpha' )
        $countUsers++;
}

var_dump($countUsers);
```

Comment: It works, but I just thought, it is possible to ignore if say:
<user name="Cajs" removed="Not Required">
And therefore by checking for the "removed" part it won't add to the counter.

Comment: You need to explain your answer. SO is not just about answering questions, it's about teaching how to do thing.

Comment: You have a point. My apologies. I have an idea whereby to count all the active users. Therefore by removing the "removed=<reason>" entries from the count, this will show the active users. I was wondering if you could teach me how to modify the above code shared by @mandrake which will support this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With DomDocument it would just be:

```
$xpath->query('//user[server[text()="Alpha"]]/network')->length;
```

I'm sure it's the same in simplexml but I never use that lib.

For the second part it's:

```
$xpath->query('//user[not(@removed) and server[text()="Alpha"]]/network')->length;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would import the xml file with DomDocument, any ideas @pguardiario